# Hanging a punching bag in the basement

Tags: basement, mounting, hanging

I have hung a punching bag weighing about **100 pounds** in my unfinished basement.  I just want to make sure that the setup would not harm my basement in any way.

[image]

- **The boards are 2*6 lumber**
- **The screws I used to hang the boards are 3.5 inches long (8 per
  board)**
- **[This](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00076ZE0I/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) is the heavy bag hanger**
- **[This](https://www.amazon.ca/Ringside-Heavy-Duty-Bag-Spring/dp/B006K408LG/ref=pd_bxgy_200_img_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=MNT17PVGBJ025KB524JY) is the heavy duty spring**

Answers that I am interested in:

Would this setup

1. **Cause any sort of damage to the basement?**
2. **be able to hold punches on the bag?**
3. **When I did not use the spring, it caused a lot of vibration.  Would that be damaging?**

Comment: vibration will cause lightbulbs to fail. ... no sure about fluorescents ... the boards may pull away from the floor joists because it looks like the 2x6 are not right against the joists and may have a bit of wobble in them

Comment: Thank you..  I did not even consider the light bulbs.  The spring did reduce the vibrations.

Comment: secure the bag chain to the spring more securely than shown in the photo. The spring hook at the bottom may open under impact and disengage the chain from the hook. If you don't secure that hook, be sure to have video cameras running when the bag is in use. (grin)

Comment: The floor above is a larger concern than the basement. I wouldn't hang it below a tiled floor or china cabinet if I could avoid it.

Comment: I'm a 6'3 guy trying to hang the punching bag as high as possible in the basement.  which is why the bag chain is all messed up like that.  Also the floor above has hardwood with no cabinets.

Comment: What purpose do the 2x6 boards serve? Why not go right into the joists? Also, if you are trying to raise the bag you could mount boards inside the joists or even consider mounting to the sub-floor (but I'm not clear from this picture what you have for sub-floor).

Comment: I'm pretty new at this and I was afraid that I would damage the joist if I hang it from a single one, so I thought by this method, I could spread the weight around between the 3 joists.  I think the subfloor is pretty thin, you cannot see it in the picture but there are nails through it which were used when we put in hardwood floors in the room above.

Comment: @Stanwood - It was the right thing to install the 2x6s across the three joists. If the punching bag was installed onto just one joist that one would be subject to torsional twist as the bag was clobbered in a direction perpendicular to the joist direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read some of the comments here and tend to agree with several points raised.

1. The 2x6 pieces should be 100% tight and snug to the bottoms of the joists above. It looks like you tried to screw them into place without a clearance hole in the 2x6 which is what could lead to the type of fit shown. You should at least remove and reinstall them correctly.
2. You could do better than the screws you used by using some lag bolts instead. These will need a washer under the lag bolt head, a clearance sized hole through the 2x6s and a pilot sized hole in the joists. The clearance hole allows the lag bolt to pass through the 2x6. The pilot hole is the inner diameter of the lag bolt threaded region. I suggest 5/6 x 3.5" sized bolts. The bolts and washers would look like shown below.

[image]

3. You need to secure the chain to spring connection better. As it is now the chain could jump off the spring hook under robust usage of the punching bag. A better way would be to use a short bolt two washers and a nut to fasten the chain link to the spring hook. I suggest using at least a 5/16" diameter bolt if not even a 3/8" size. It may be necessary to spread the chain link to get the bolt through.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, The 2x6 lumber that I got was not level.  I may need to get new lumber.  I'm kind of new to this, never ever thought that lumber from store would not be level.

Answer (score 0):

You've done the right thing by spreading the load across 3 joists. They need to be tightened, so flush with the joists.

Comment: I think you mean "tight to the joists". Flush means something else. At any rate, this seems more like a comment (on a very old question) than an answer.